# Is there any algorithm to draw lines between two points and avoid intersession with other elements?

Tags: algorithm, graphics

[image]

Here is the example, I got point A to point B. Most easy eay to do is using the red line. But the blue circle is in the middle. So, is there any algorithm to find out the green path? If yes, please advise.

Comment: I don't know what your purpose is but its standard requirement in mobile robotics. You can find obstacle avoidance algorithms online.

Comment: How are the objects given, and how do you score how good a green line is?

Comment: Are the obstacles always circles? Can there be many such obstacles? Is it always possible to arrive at B - in other words, can A be closed in by obstacles? It would be great if you can upload an example image of the most complex scenario.